# Understanding row estimation for timestamp in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.4

I have a table (call it `tbl`) that's got the column `registration_date timestamp`. Now, for simplicity I set the following statistic parameter:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN registration_date SET STATISTICS 2;
ANALYZE tbl;
```

and than I've got the following statistic for the table (from `pg_stats`)

```
avg_width n_distinct  most_common_vals most_common_freqs    
    8         -1             ""               ""                   
                         histogram_bounds
 2012-03-26 10:32:15.379,2013-11-05 19:33:09.828,2015-11-19 14:39:04.676
```

And the query

`SELECT reltuples,relpages FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'tbl'`

returns this:

```
reltuples relpages
 240656     2476
```

Now, I execute the query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE tbl.registration_date > '2014-11-11' -- 2014-11-11 is not in histgrom_bounds
```

And got the following ananlyzed plan:

```
Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..5484.20 rows=60441 width=47) (actual time=3.872..26.406 rows=604 loops=1)
  Filter: (registration_date > '2014-11-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 240052
Planning time: 0.119 ms
Execution time: 26.439 ms
```

***QUESTION:*** How is the estimated number of rows computed in my case? I don't understand the `60441` rows count in the plan. Note that

```
SELECT reltuples/4 FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'tbl'
```

returns `60164` which is less than `60441`.